# Geodesics under coordinate transformation

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, geodesic

Consider components of metric tensor $g'$ in a coordinate system
$$g'= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
xy & 1 \\
1 & xy \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We can transformation rule which brings $g'$ to euclidean metric $g=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$, namely
$$A^T*g'*A=g$$
where $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{xy}} & 1 \\
1 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{xy}}\\
\end{pmatrix}$ .

Levi-Civita connection for $g$ has all components as zero but not all components are vanishing for $g'$. 
**So if I want to find geodseics given $g'$ I could find appropriate transformation where $g'$ looks like $g$ but in this case geodesics are going to be straight lines given ANY $g'$.**

Is this a wrong statement?